# D3 Update/Redraw SVG at Set Intervals

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an animation where points on a plane are encapsulated dynamically by a polygon ([gift-wrapping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm)). I am using a path SVG to draw the polygon, however, I notice that as points transform around the plane and are added to/removed from the perimeter of the polygon, the entire polygon will rotate to adjust during it's transitions, which looks messy and makes for a poor visualization.

I can see that many examples ([example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366)) involve redrawing (instead of transitioning) the entire path SVG with new data when an event occurs. **I was wondering if there is any way I can redraw the path at set intervals, such as once every x milliseconds, or once each time the points are transformed.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to understand without an example of what your solution currently looks like.

That said, I noticed the bl.ock example you linked, and how it redraws instead of transitioning. If you want to avoid a full redraw, you'll need to separate out solely the changed SVG subsections in some way, so they can be individually targeted. Like an array of d3 SVG objects, or something.